# Proving upper bound for Bias of truncated sample mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, inequality, robust-statistics

So we have the truncated sample mean:

$\begin{align}
    \hat{\mu}^{\tau} := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i =1}^n \psi_{\tau}(X_i)
\end{align}$

Where the truncation operator is defined as:

$\begin{align}
    \psi_{\tau}(x) = (|x| \wedge \tau) \; \text{sign}(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}$

The bias for this truncated estimator is then defined as:

Bias $:= \mathbb{E}(\hat{\mu}^{\tau}) - \mu$

And I saw the inequality:

$\begin{align}
    |\text{Bias}| = |\mathbb{E}[(X - \text{sign}(X)\tau) \mathbb{I}_{\{|X| > \tau\}}]| \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{\tau}
\end{align}$

But I am not sure how this was derived.

The assumptions on the data are that they are i.i.d and have finite variance.

Comment: The final form looks similar to Markov's inequality, I suspect they're related

Comment: Yes, so far I have been trying to work out how to apply markovs or chebyshevs to get the inequality.

Comment: I asked the question elsewhere, and received a [solution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611794/proving-upper-bound-for-bias-of-truncated-sample-mean?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attemp.

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|\text{Bias}| &\le \frac{1}{n} \; \mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\bigg|\tau \; \text{sign}(X_i) - |X_i| \bigg| \; \mathbb{I}_{\{ |X_i| > \tau \}} \\
&\le \frac{1}{n} \; \mathbb{E}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigg(\tau \; \mathbb{I}_{\{ |X_i| > \tau \}} + |X_i| \mathbb{I}_{\{ |X_i| > \tau \}} \bigg) \\
&= \tau \; \mathbb{P}(|X| > \tau) + \frac{\text{cost}}{n} \qquad \text{for n large enough}\\
&\le \tau \; \mathbb{P}(|X| > \tau) \\
&\le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{\tau}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

where in the last inequality I used the Generalized Markov's inequality with the second moment

Comment: Thanks for this, I put up the same question on cross-validated see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611794/proving-upper-bound-for-bias-of-truncated-sample-mean?noredirect=1#comment1136371_611794) and got another solution.